# Magento wordpress fishpig not showing related posts

Tags: php, wordpress, magento

I have a magento v 1.7.0.2 and I installed a wordpress as a blog , integrating it with fishpig. Although I installed YARPP plugin in wordpress admin, my related posts are not appearing on post page.

Do you have any thoughts that could point me in the right direction ? Or maybe is there a way to display related posts manually by modifying fishpig templates ?
Thank you.

Comment: Is your Wordpress installation a multisite instance?

Comment: My wordpress is a simple wordpress instalation at domain/blog of magento. I suppose it is not a multisite.